When a median of a triangle is drawn, are the two smaller triangles guaranteed to be similar?
Let's say the following median is drawn:

I get that $\triangle$ABD and $\triangle$ACD are guaranteed to have equal areas since they share Point A as a vertex, have congruent bases $\bigl(\overline{\text{BD}}$ and $\overline{\text{DC}}\bigr)$ and have the same height $\bigl($the altitude from Point A to $\overline{\text{BC}}\bigr)$.  I can see that this doesn't imply the smaller triangles are congruent, but does it imply the smaller triangles are similar?  If so, what is a proof of that?

They are not similar as the angles are not equal. (Assuming the common definition of similar).

Think of a scalene triangle $ABC$ (which is neither isosceles nor equilateral). We have $\measuredangle ADC=\measuredangle DAB + \measuredangle ABD$. Therefore, $\measuredangle ADC\neq \measuredangle DAB$ and $\measuredangle ADC\neq \measuredangle ABD$. Furthermore, $\measuredangle ADC\neq \measuredangle BDA$, because they are supplementary, i.e., $\measuredangle ADC = 180- \measuredangle BDA$. Hence, none of the three angles of $\triangle ABD$ is equal to $\measuredangle ADC$ of $\triangle ABD$.
